# web request through ssh

Tags: user-interface, web, ssh

at my school I can access an online library and the documents can only be accessed from computers within the schools network. However I want to access them from my home computer. I can ssh to a computer at the school and in theory could run an X-window environment, open a webbrowser at the schools computer and view the documents, but the graphical interface is rather slow.

I wonder if there is a way to run the webbrowser on my own computer while I do the webrequest through the ssh connection.

Does anybody know how to do this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your school not provide a VPN? That is usually the normal setup for off-campus resources.

Comment: it does for some services, but the library is licensced only for the computers within my special department

Comment: You could use [ssh port forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) and then access the server by browsing to `http://localhost`.  But actually this question is quite offtopic for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VPN would be the obvious option but since you haven't mentioned anything about that, you could try using your SSH connection as a VPN (I've never done this so no idea if it will work). http://docs.cslabs.clarkson.edu/wiki/Use_SSH_as_a_VPN

Comment: i dont know much about vpn, can i use it for this task or would the computer at the school have to be configured in a certain way, how could i tell ?

Comment: vpn is only really easier if it is configured for you (by the it department). if you need a do-it-yourself-solution the ssh socks proxy is the simplest solution.

Comment: it works perfectly with the description provided in the link and is actually quite fast. it only didnt work when i chose 50000 as the port, i am using 9090 now. thanks for your help and sorry if i was off topic.